# Why is the de Rham space named after de Rham?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, manifolds, homotopy-theory, schemes

One can define the **de Rham space / stack** of (say) a scheme by identifying infinitesimally closed points. Modules over this space, also called **crystals**, may be regarded as an algebraic analogue of flat connections on a smooth vector bundle over a manifold.

My question is why we call this space the de Rham space. My guess is that this space is related to algebraic de Rham cohomology (or crystalline cohomology, whatever that is) of a scheme, but references on this topic say nothing about this. Differential-geometric intuition would be more than welcome.

Comment: Are you talking about the infinitesimal site? I've never heard it called the de Rham space. The cohomology of the infinitesimal site is the de Rham cohomology. Maybe googling these key phrases will help.

Comment: @AlexYoucis, I am following the terminology of a note by Lurie called "Notes on crystals and algebraic D-modules." The n-Lab suggests that the infinitesimal site is the big site associated to the de Rham space, at least in characteristic zero.

Comment: After some Googling it would appear that, in characteristic zero, the sheaf cohomology of the structure sheaf $\mathcal{O}_X$ of the de Rham space (or, equivalently, the cohomology of $\mathcal{O}_X$ as a sheaf on the infinitesimal site) coincides with the algebraic de Rham cohomology. That sounds like what I'm after. Do you know if there is an analogue in differential geometry?

Comment: I don't think that result needs characteristic $0$, it's just that in characteristic $p$ algebraic de Rham isn't what you want (you want crystalline cohomology so you replace the infinitesimal site with the crystalline site). I don't even know what this means in differential geometry since I don't know what infinitesimals mean.

Comment: I always thought it was because modules on it are flat connections, and their cohomology is de Rham cohomology, like you are saying. I've definitely seen algebraic flat connections referred to as "de Rham local systems", especially when they are next to topological ("Betti") local systems.

Comment: @AlexYoucis There are two comments: 1. if I understand correctly, the de Rham stack (or space) is not the infinitesimal site, but rather a prestack (Def 1.1.1 in https://arxiv.org/abs/1111.2087v4). They should be related. For a more recent work, you could look for Drinfeld's stacky approach to prismatic cohomology; 2. In char $p$, the infinitesimal cohomology does not recover the algebraic de Rham cohomology — the crystalline cohomology does.

Comment: @AlexYoucis To be more precise, the infinitesimal cohomology of an $\mathbb F_p$-scheme recovers the $\mathbb F_p$-étale cohomology, both of which are Frobenius fixed points of the $\mathbb Z_p$-crystalline cohomology. See Ogus' paper http://www.numdam.org/item/ASENS_1975_4_8_3_295_0/